# c# can I type the code I want to execute in LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq

A very simple question. I just happen to be practicing LINQ now, I want to know if I can type the condition in "where" part of LINQ? 
for example

```
from a in myPerson
where a.Age > 15
select a;
```

and then I get to type my own condition in run-time. If I want to get the age greater than 25 this time, or I want to filter it not by age but by Names now. So I will just type

```
where a.Name == "John"
```

I wonder if it can be done.

Thanks in any help!

Comment: maybe you need [Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

Comment: Rephrase your question so it isn't a yes/no question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hardcoding your value in the condition, use a variable. So your condition can be handled with different values during runtime

```
var age = //put your code for retrieving age
from a in myPerson
where a.Age > age 
select a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compose IQueryables. Just append additional `Where`, `OrderBy` etc clauses as needed:

```
// passed as parameters
int age;
string name;
bool sortByName;

var persons = _dbContext.Person;

// always filter by Age
var result = persons.Where(p => p.Age > age);

// additionally filter by Name if some condition is met
if (age > 25) {
    result = result.Where(p => p.Name == name);
}

// sort depending on parameter
if (sortByName) {
    result = result.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
}
else {
    result = result.OrderBy(p => p.Age);
}

// query will be executed when you enumerate the IQueryable
return result.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a IQueryable

```
var ageConditiion = 15;
var originQuery = from a in myPerson select a;
var result1 = originQuery.Where(a => a.Age > ageConditiion).ToList();
var result2 = originQuery.Where(a => a.Name == "John").ToList();
```

Queryable wont send any request to database.